# How to pass JSON as a prop?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component that gets 2 props, one is another component and the second is a JSON file:

```
interface HeaderProps {
  title: ReactElement<typeof Title>;
  data: any;
}
```

The prop 'title' is very specific and shows that only the component `<Title />` can be passed there.

How can I specify the type of the prop `data` so instead of `any` it will be for JSON type only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON in Typescript is just `Object`:

```
data: Object
```

Comment: So I tried that before but I get an error when I try to map over the data from that JSON file: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Now I got a different error, Property 'image' does not exist on type 'object'. Do I need to specify something in addition to Object[] ?

Comment: Well in that case you should (as always in TS) be as specific as possible, so specify the actual component/function/class type, when you know it. Actually an array of them (or at least a choice between them using `data: Cmp1[] | Cmp2[]`).

Comment: this is the RIGHT answer to the question

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for an "object" with dynamic key of any type.

```
data: { [key:string]: any }// if array then {[key:string]: any}[]
```

Comment: Unless you want to specify the object props, you can use this "wild object"